# type hint for return value of a factory method?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I am wondering the correct way to perform type hinting for a Factory method in Python 3.6+. Ideally I would like to use a union however I am importing a from an auto-generated Protobuf module with a large number of different classes within it. What is the best way to go about handling a situation like this while utilizing type hinting.

I currently have something like:

```
from testing import test as t

def generate_class(class_type: str) -> # What should go here?
    if class_type in t.__dict__:
        return t.__dict__[class_type]

    ex_msg = "{} not found in the module library".format(class_type)
    raise KeyError(ex_msg)
```

Comment: Short of an explicitly defined `Union` based on the contents of `t`, I don't see how you can use anything more specific than `Any`.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but wanted to double check that there wasn't another more explicit way.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer but I think I should mention, you don't have to use type hints everywhere. If you want to do that, you may as well just be coding in Cython then or some other statically typed language. The cases where a function can return one of many different types are precisely those cases where you are using the dynamic types property of Python, and hence precisely the case where it doesn't make sense to use type hinting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the runnable code below matches your use case, but if it does, then this kind of situation can be handled by using `TypeVar` to define the return type.

`TypeVar` is described in [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) in its [`Generics`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#generics) section.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Text
#from testing import test as t
t = type('test', (object,), {'Text': Text, 'bytes': bytes})


LibraryType = TypeVar(t.__dict__)

def generate_class(class_type: str) -> LibraryType:
    if class_type in t.__dict__:
        return t.__dict__[class_type]

    ex_msg = "{} not found in the module library".format(class_type)
    raise KeyError(ex_msg)

print("generate_class('Text'):", generate_class('Text'))      # -> generate_class('Text'): <class 'str'>
print("generate_class('bytes'):", generate_class('bytes'))    # -> generate_class('bytes'): <class 'bytes'>
print("generate_class('foobar'):", generate_class('foobar'))  # -> KeyError: 'foobar not found in the module library'
```